# Converting date types for datepicker entry

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm working on a calendar for wordpress, so I have the following issue: the data i get from the query does not match the datepicker format

The parts to acquire the arrays are following

```php
<?php
$my_array = array();

// the query
$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'eventos',
    'order'=>'ASC');

$posts = get_posts( $args );

if ( $posts ) {
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $my_array[]  = array(
            'Title' => $post->post_title,
            'Date' => date_format(date_create('@'. strtotime(get_field('data-event'))), 'r') . "\n"
            ,
        );
    }
}
print_r($my_array);
?>

var events =  [
    { Title: "Evento 1", Date: new Date("05/20/2020")},
    { Title: "Evento 2", Date: new Date("05/20/2020")},
    { Title: "Evento 3", Date: new Date("05/21/2020")},];
```

[ConsoleLog Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSKCv.png)

any ideas how can I make them equal?

Comment: Where are you comparing these dates? (Are you trying to compare the formatted output string? That's generally not a great way to compare dates) Have you considered using a unix timestamp?

Comment: I'm trying to create a Datepícker calendar using custom posts from WordPress. Datepicker entry uses (new Date("mm/dd/yyyy") and converts to RCF (through new Date command). So what's missing is to make both inputs the same...